# Python Windows Registry: Display List of Profiles

Tags: python, windows

I am new to Windows Registries and I'm currently trying to get a list of profile names from my Windows registries using Python, but I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. My code is the following:

```
from winreg import *
def get_profiles():

    regKey = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
        r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList')
    recent = QueryValueEx(regKey,'DisplayName')[0]
    recent_list = []
    for subkey in recent:
        recent_list.append(QueryValueEx(regKey,subkey)[0])
    return recent_list
```

When I try to run the above, I get the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-6261438d1fdc> in <module>()
----> 1 l = get_profiles()

<ipython-input-44-f572c6ac8843> in get_profiles()
      4     regKey = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
      5         r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList')
----> 6     recent = QueryValueEx(regKey,'DisplayName')[0]
      7     recent_list = []
      8     for subkey in recent:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have a hunch that the `'DisplayName'` part is wrong, how should I correct it?

Comment: You are trying to query the `DisplayName` on the path `SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\ProfileList` which does exist.

Comment: "You are trying to query the DisplayName on the path SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\ProfileList which does exist." Don't you mean does NOT exist?

Comment: The path `SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\ProfileList` exists. That is why `OpenKey` does not raised any exception. The issue is with the `DisplayName`. You should open the `regedit`(If you are in windows) and navigate to the path and verify the `value_name`.

Comment: Could you please clarify precisely, since I'm very new to this, in my regedit, when I click on ProfileList , on my right hand side, I see a list of values, "Default", "ProfilesDirectory", "ProgramData", and "Public". Are these what I'm supposed to use?

Comment: For the given path(`SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`) the `QueryValueEx` function will work only with `Default", "ProfilesDirectory", "ProgramData", and "Public"`. For all other non existing keys it will raise `FileNotFoundError`

Comment: Yes I think I understand now, when I input "Default" instead of "DisplayName" I of course get "%SystemDrive%\Users\Default", but ultimately how do I get the actual profile lists? Am I missing something?

Comment: If you look at the sub keys of `ProfileList` you could see the list of all profiles on your computer(eg: S-17-13-14 ). So if you are looking for say `SID` of all user profile you have to iterate though the subkeys then query the `SID`

Comment: How do I query SID? Could you please give me an example? Or link me?

Comment: This is what `QueryValueEx` function actually does.

Comment: Ok, so how do I get the subkeys of the profilelist?

Comment: I just post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EnumKey` API to *get the sub keys of an open registry key*.

> `winreg.EnumKey(key, index)`
>
> Enumerates subkeys of an open registry key,
> returning a string.
>
> `key` is an already open key, or one of the predefined `HKEY_*` constants.
>
> `index` is an integer that identifies the index of the key to retrieve.

```
from contextlib import suppress
from winreg import \
    (OpenKey,
     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
     QueryInfoKey,
     QueryValueEx,
     EnumKey)


PROFILE_REGISTRY = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\WindowsNT\\CurrentVersion\\ProfileList"


def get_profile_attribute(*, attribute):
    profile_to_sub_key_map = {}
    with OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, PROFILE_REGISTRY) as key:
        number_of_sub_keys, _, _ = QueryInfoKey(key)  # The `QueryInfoKey` Returns information about a key, as a tuple.
        # At the index 0  will be An integer giving the number of sub keys 
        # this key has.

        for index in range(number_of_sub_keys):
            sub_key_name = EnumKey(key, index)
            # Open the sub keys one by one and fetch the attribute.
            with OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                         f"{PROFILE_REGISTRY}\\{sub_key_name}") as sub_key:
                with suppress(FileNotFoundError):
                    registry_value, _ = QueryValueEx(sub_key, attribute)
                    profile_to_sub_key_map.update({sub_key_name: registry_value})

    return profile_to_sub_key_map


print(get_profile_attribute(attribute='ProfileImagePath'))
```

Also note that as per the documentation.

The `HKEY` object implements `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` and thus supports the context protocol for the with statement:

```
with OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "foo") as key:
    ...  # work with key
```

will automatically close key when control leaves the with block.

Comment: Is it also possible to get other properties this way? Including last logins?

Comment: Don't query the number of keys. That's prone to race conditions. Just handle the `OSError` exception with `winerror == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS` (259). Also, the `sub_key` handle should be opened relative to the parent handle,  `key`. Using the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` pseudo-handle (for "\Registry\Machine") unnecessarily reparses most of the path.